# TYPO3 Flux: Hide custom FCEs in new content wizard

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-12.x

I'm trying to limit the available content elements when using the new content wizard for nested ce.

Is there any option like flux's `allowedContentTypes` for *tt_content* in general?

Actually I have two custom content elements: *accordion* and *accordionelement*
Within *accordion* there is a grid column with `allowedContentTypes` set to *accordionelement*, that works fine – only this element shows up in that new content wizard within *accordion*.
Now I would like to only show *accordion* when adding new content to a page.

I could hide *accordionelement* by modifing PageTS `mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems`, but then it's gone within *accordion* too.

Comment: Maybe EXT:content_defender is what you are looking for: https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/content_defender